# One Volume Chumash with Rashi Menukad

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, pentateuch-chumash

I'm looking for a new Chumash for school.

I want it to be one volume, with Rashi menukad.  Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

There aren't so many options if you want it both one-volume and *menukad*. The two options I know are

- The [Koren Israel - Complete Humash](https://www.korenpub.com/koren_en_usd/koren/tanakh-bible/koren-israel-humash/complete-humash-rashi-onkelos-1-volume.html), see it inside [here](https://www.korenpub.com/media/productattachments/files/f/i/file_10.pdf). It uses a Koren font, incl. for Rashi
- The new Hebrew-English [Steinsaltz Humash](https://www.korenpub.com/koren_en_usd/koren/new-releases-koren/the-steinsaltz-humash.html), which just came out. I have received a preview edition of Bereishit and it is really beautiful. It has a new interpolated commentary from R Steinsaltz woven into the English (like the [Kehot Chabad Humash](http://store.kehotonline.com/prodinfo.asp?number=ESE-TORA.LSE#) does with Rashi), the same Rashi menukad as the Koren humash above as well as discussion points and pictures (like their new Koren Steinsaltz gemara) - tell me if you want to see pictures inside

If you are willing to trade off one-volume for more commentaries, the [Artscroll Mikraot Gedolot](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422616000.html) would be an alternative. That one doesn't have an English translation.